# Gap between sector 1-2048

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

The MBR size is 512 bytes and is usually in the first sector.

What is the  gap between sector 1-2048?

I read on IBM website: "leave room for bootloader code in the unallocated space between the MBR and the first partition."

Does it means the binary bootloader code?
We know the binary bootloader code is in the main ext4 Linux partition.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please rephrase your question in a clearer way so that it's easy to find a possible answer. Thank you. Happy asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally in the pre-UEFI firmware era, the first 512 byte sector on the disk was the Master Boot Record that contained the grub stage 1 loader and the partition table. The following 63 sectors were the BIOS compat region that contained the grub stage 1.5.  So, in all there were 64 * 512 (or 32K) reserved at the start of the disk.  Nowadays, the reserved region after the MBR is 2047 sectors; I believe is so there is enough space to allocate a UEFI boot partition there at a later date if it has not been installed already.

Comment: It has always been more to do with (flawed notions of) partition alignment than to do with leaving an MBR virus area for GRUB and its ilk.  (-:  http://superuser.com/questions/297232/ http://superuser.com/questions/331446/ http://superuser.com/questions/393914/